# PostgreSQL grouped rolling average (for multiple labels)

Tags: postgresql

I could not find a clear example of this online.

I want a moving average for the last 2 days based on this data:

```
create table expenses as (
  select 'food' as expense, 5.0 as cost, current_date as date
  union select 'food', 5.0, current_date - 1
  union select 'food', 4.0, current_date - 2
  union select 'food', 4.0, current_date - 3
  union select 'food', 3.0, current_date - 4
  union select 'food', 3.0, current_date - 5
  union select 'entertainment', 9.0, current_date
  union select 'entertainment', 9.0, current_date - 1
  union select 'entertainment', 8.0, current_date - 2
  union select 'entertainment', 8.0, current_date - 3
  union select 'entertainment', 7.0, current_date - 4
  union select 'entertainment', 7.0, current_date - 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I put together

```
select
 expense,
 date,
 cost,
 avg(cost) over
  (partition by expense order by date rows 2 preceding) as rolling_avg_cost
from expenses
```

which gives the result:

```
expense       date                                cost rolling_avg_cost
entertainment Thursday, March 23, 2017 12:00 AM   7    7
entertainment Friday, March 24, 2017 12:00 AM     7    7
entertainment Saturday, March 25, 2017 12:00 AM   8    7.3
entertainment Sunday, March 26, 2017 12:00 AM     8    7.6
entertainment Monday, March 27, 2017 12:00 AM     9    8.3
entertainment Tuesday, March 28, 2017 12:00 AM    9    8.6
food          Thursday, March 23, 2017 12:00 AM   3    3
food          Friday, March 24, 2017 12:00 AM     3    3
food          Saturday, March 25, 2017 12:00 AM   4    3.3
food          Sunday, March 26, 2017 12:00 AM     4    3.6
food          Monday, March 27, 2017 12:00 AM     5    4.3
food          Tuesday, March 28, 2017 12:00 AM    5    4.6
```

As can be seen, **the window for the rolling average is 3 days inclusive of the current row** (i.e. the current row plus the previous two, all divided by 3).